# install Touch on Nexus 4, via Trisquel in VM on MacAir

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Phone verifies unlocked.
Trisquel can see the Nexus via USB
update and upgrade run successfully.

Terminal reports successful restart.
Android bootloader comes up on the Nexus
Terminal reports < waiting for device >
USB debugging connected
Developer Mode enabled.

I feel as if I am missing one small, simple, step.

Anyone out there know what it might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking in this question.

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu anywhere in there?

Comment: *Trisquel* is a computer operating system based on the Ubuntu Linux distribution, with all of the **non-free** components removed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisquel

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a component intentionally not included in 'Trisquel'.

from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisquel

> *Trisquel* is a computer operating system based on the Ubuntu Linux distribution, with all of the **non-free** components removed. The project aims for a fully free software system without proprietary software or firmware and uses a free version of the Linux kernel as distributed by the **Linux-libre** project. Trisquel relies on user donations. Its logo is a triskelion.

***This forum is not intended support such efforts.***

---

**OR,**

You just need to try again ..

*Some recent daily builds did **not** boot.*

Place the smartphone in 'Recovery Mode' and re-load:

**`phablet-flash -b -d mako --pending`**